# Include PDF welcome package attachment with email receipt

Tags: email, attachments

I am trying to sort out if I can include a PDF attachment for new members with their registration confirmation email. There are several different member types, each would require a different PDF. The content of the PDFs is too long to put directly into the confirmation email. The PDF contains a welcome message and information about events, benefits, and other details for new members.

I can see how to include a PDF receipt in the admin settings but no where to include any other type of PDF. I see the option to set the maximum number of files (documents, images, etc.) which can be attached to emails or activities but I can't find where to configure what files to attach.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

(Using CiviCRM 4.7.24)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Scheduled Reminders to fire x hours after Membership Start/Join Date - and specify which membership types these relate to.

You should therefore either be able to attach the PDF to these, or, better in many cases, provide a link to the PDF so the attachment isn't part of the email.